¿Cómo puedo crear dataframes en python para cada tabla de un archivo de Excel? Las tablas están en la misma hoja
Quisiera saber como puedo crear dataframes para cada una de las tablas que contiene un archivo de Excel, estas tablas se encuentran en la misma hoja y tiene espacios vacíos
El archivo se ve algo así. Estoy intentando en python con pandas pero aun no sé como dividir por tablas y que no aparezcan las filas y columnas vacias o las celdas que tienen .dat
Agradecería mucho su ayuda ya que no cuento con mucho tiempo para resolver este problema.

Cuando cargas un dataframe, el argumento usecols te permite elegir columnas y debería facilitarte lo que quieres. En esta web tienes un ejemplo)
